# Spring MVC - bind form elements to a List<Long>

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, bind

Is it possible to bind a form element to a `List<Long>`?

ie. `<form:input path="formValues[0]" />` binding to an element in `List<Long> formValues;` in the form backing object?

When I try this, it fails because Long does not have a default constructor `new Long()`.

I've worked around it by creating a dummy holder class

```
class DummyLong {
    private Long value;
    ...
}
```

making the list in the formbacking object a `List<DummyLong>` and changing the form tag to `<form:input path="formValues[0].value" />` but this seems unnecessarily hideous and I'm sure there must be a better way. Haven't been able to find it though.

Comment: Did you try `List<Long> formValues` `with <form:input path="formValues" />`?

Comment: I didn't but I have now and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, I posted. Sorry that mu answer too short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `List<Long> formValues` with `<form:input path="formValues" />`